# How much deviation (if any at all) is acceptable when housing amphibians?

Tags: temperature, frogs

Recently, I've been considering getting a Pacman frog, but have a question / concern regarding the the ideal temperature of the environment.

Most resources I've read online specify that the temperature for that particular breed of frog is around 75 - 85 during the day. Now, it tends to get rather hot in the summer where I live and occasionally, I'll turn the AC off when I'm not home, to save power, and my apartment is well insulated enough that it generally peaks around 86 - 87 by the time I get home.

I am curious, however, that since that average of 86-87 is a few degrees above the cap of the animal's ideal temperature, whether it is safe. It doesn't seem like two degrees that much, and I have read the 75-85 figure as *ideal*, but I was curious as to how much deviation from said ideal is safe when dealing with amphibians. Could I get away with a +2 deviation, or is that unsafe?